# Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.1

Tags: java, maven

I have my first multi-module program, project structure is:

```
testMods
|
├───checker
│   │ 
│   │
│   └───src
│   |   └───main
│   |       └───java
│   |       |   │  
│   |       |   │
│   |       |   └──────sample
│   |       |   |   └───Controller.java
│   |       |   |   └───Main.java
|   |       |   |   └───MainLauncher.java
│   |       |   |
|   |       |   └──────module-info.java               
│   |       |
|   |       └────resouces
|   |          └───META-INF  
|   |
|   └────pom.xml
|             
└───TextInputProgram
|   │   
|   │
|   └───src
|   |   └───main
|   |       └───java
|   |           │  
|   |           │
|   |           └───project
|   |           |    └───Name1.java
|   |           |    └───Name2.java
|   |           |    └───Name3.java
|   |           |    └───Name4.java 
|   |           |             
|   |           └───module-info.java
|   |            
|   └────pom.xml
|
└────pom.xml
```

POM inside *checker*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>testMods</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>checker</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>TextInputProgram</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <mainClass>sample.MainLauncher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

POM inside *TextInputProgram*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>testMods</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>TextInputProgram</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

main POM (testMods):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testMods</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>checker</module>
        <module>TextInputProgram</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>

                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Automatic-Module-Name>selenium-api</Automatic-Module-Name>
                            <Automatic-Module-Name>selenium-chrome-driver</Automatic-Module-Name>
                        </manifestEntries>

                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>sample.MainLauncher</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I'm trying to build as *jar with all dependencies* using `maven-assembly-plugin`, I'm getting always the issue:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.1:single (make-assembly) on project testMods: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.1:single for parameter source: Cannot find 'source' in class org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration
```

The same issue will be even if I change the version of maven-assembly-plugin using path:

```
\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-assembly-plugin
```

Deleting *org folder* using `\.m2\repository\org` path, didn't help to solve this issue. When maven reloaded all dependencies, I get the error: `Unable to parse configuration of mojo` again.

I've noticed that instead of getting single jar for all modules, I get separately two jars, but not single for all. During compiling, I get *target*-folders just for separated modules, but not for main POM.

If I delete in main POM:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
     <id>make-assembly</id>
     <phase>package</phase>
     <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
     </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Then I don't see this error during *packaging* and *compiling*. And plugin works, but I'll get separated jars only like:

- *checker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*
- *TextInputProgram-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar* (in their own modules folders)

If I run one of them, I see:

```
no main manifest attribute, in D:\IdeaProject\testMods\testMods\checker\target\checker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**But I generated in resource folder MANIFEST, as you can see my structure.**
To create it, I choosed these options in *Project Structure -> Artifacts*:
[image]

In addition, I tried to use in main POM `maven-shade-plugin` instead of `maven-assembly-plugin`. In this case I can compile and package, but again I have two different jars as separated modules like:

- *original-TextInputProgram-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*
- *TextInputProgram-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*
- *checker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*
- *original-checker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*

but not main jar that includes all of this.

Can somemone tell me what I need to correct here to get finally jar that includes all modules inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a build by `removing` following two lines

```
<source>11</source>
<target>11</target>
```

from `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin section of `parent`(testMods) pom, and the build was `success`.

As per the doc of [assembly:single](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html), there is no any tag called `source` or `target` defined as valid parameter, thus plugin fails with cannot find `'source'`(the first invalid tag)